# Convert DER encoded X509 certificate buffer to windows CERT_CONTEXT structure

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, cryptoapi

I have a X509 certificate, which was created using OpenSSL and exported to DER blob using OpenSSL i2d_X509() function.

Is there any way to convert DER certificate blob into Windows [CERT_CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377189(VS.85).aspx) structure?

I know, that it could be done using temporary file,  CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_FILENAME) and CertEnumCertificatesInStore() functions. But could not find any way without using temporary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.
It can be done using **::CertCreateCertificateContext** function:

```
std::vector<BYTE> certificate;
// ... acquire DER encoded certificate using i2d_X509()
// ...
PCCERT_CONTEXT context = ::CertCreateCertificateContext(
    X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, 
    certificate.data(), 
    certificate.size());
// ...
// ...
::CertFreeCertificateContext(context);
```